# Error al empaquetar un .py en .exe con pyinstaller

Tags: python, anaconda

Estoy intentando crear un .exe con pyinstaller de mi aplicacion .py
Trabajo con anaconda y Spyder, me genera bien el exe pero cuando voy a ejecutarlo obtengo el siguiente error:
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows"
in "".

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Comment: reviisa esto te ayudara: https://blog.inventic.eu/2015/09/qt-this-application-failed-to-start-because-it-could-not-find-or-load-the-qt-platform-plugin-windows/

Comment: Seguramente se debe a la falta de una dll o a la incapacidad para localizarla, posiblemente `qwindows.dll`. Es importante que agregues siempre un [mcve], que muestre el código objetivo (o como mínimo las librerías que usas e importas), cómo y con que argumentos lanzas pyinstaller y cómo configuras el `.spec` si lo haces (si estás intentándolo con el modo `onefile` o no, si has desactivado o no UPX, ...), también es de ayuda ejecutar con la opción `--debug` y mostrar la salida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

te falta una librería dentro del paquete de distribución,

- intenta crear un directorio primero de distribución,
- corre el programa con el exe generado (a manera de un launcher).
- verifica los errores que te da, comprueba los trackball completos y verifica donde hace falta el archivo, o que modulo lo esta llamando.
- intenta añadir manualmente las bibliotecas necesarias para el
  programa, estas las puedes sacar directamente del directorio de instalación en tu path.

una vez que encuentres todo lo que necesitas, añade las dependencias al archivo **spect** para que las empaquete dentro de la aplicación, o de manera que siempre te genere el ejecutable y dependa de un directorio en la misma carpeta.

**Un consejo:**

la manera mas rápida que puedes usar para desarrollar la aplicacion, es generar un archivo `__init__.py` que se encargue de importar la estructura principal, de esta manera puedes poner, por ejemplo :

```
import __all_modules_needed__
from app import main_loop
mainloop()
exit(0)
```

El cual es apuntado directamente en el archivo spec como programa principal, este sera añadido al exe y tratara de importar las clases principales necesarias de manera automática y luego, para no perder tiempo en re-compilar el paquete cada vez que generes una modificación, solo alteras el programa en `app.py` y los cambios seran notados directamente, ya que al empaquetar el archivo de lanzamiento, se empaquetan las bibliotecas base, mas algunas dependencias de python. permitiendo así disminuir los tiempos entre versiones, a parte, de que permite una carga mas rápida dado que no tiene que desempaquetar todo el contenido del EXE a carpetas temporales.